# Two threads print even and odd numbers between 0 to 5 alternately in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, alternate

I'm trying to get the result below running 2 threads alternately. *Between 0 to 5, thread `A` prints even numbers and thread `B` prints odd numbers (I use **Python 3.8.5**):

```
A:0
B:1
A:2
B:3
A:4
B:5
```

So, with global variables, locks and `while` statements, I created the code below to try to get the result above:

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
owner = "A"
i = 0

def test1():
    global owner, i
    while i <= 5:
        lock.acquire()
        if owner == "A":
            print(owner + ":" + str(i))
            owner = "B"
            i += 1
        lock.release()

def test2():
    global owner, i
    while i <= 5:
        lock.acquire()
        if owner == "B":
            print(owner + ":" + str(i))
            owner = "A"
            i += 1
        lock.release()

A = threading.Thread(target=test1)
B = threading.Thread(target=test2)

A.start()
B.start()

A.join()
B.join()
```

But, the code above got the result below with `A:6`. *Thread `A` printed even number `6`:

```
A:0
B:1
A:2
B:3
A:4
B:5
A:6 # Here
```

I couldn't find any mistakes so how can I get the proper result without `A:6`? And, why did I get the result with `A:6`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing the issue, is that the thread is still within the while loop when `i` moves from `5` to `6`. The thread seems to obtain lock before the value is updated. i.e. The speed of release and lock is quicker than the assignment of `i`. So the thread goes through one more round, but the only check you have is if the owner is equal to `A` or `B`. So you have to once again have the check in place to test that `i<=5`.

If you had a single thread, then you would not have this issue, but because you are using two threads, you have to think of them as different entities, doing their own jobs. While `i` is being updated in one thread, the other thread is still spinning and checking, locking and unlocking.


The best way to visualise the thread actions is to have `print` statements within the lock (before the if-statement) - to see what each thread is up to.

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
owner = "A"
i = 0

def test1():
    global owner, i
    while i <= 5:
        lock.acquire()  # Here
        if owner == "A" and i<=5:
            print(owner + ":" + str(i))
            owner = "B"
            i += 1
        lock.release()

def test2():
    global owner, i
    while i <= 5:
        lock.acquire()  # Here
        if owner == "B" and i<=5:
            print(owner + ":" + str(i))
            owner = "A"
            i += 1
        lock.release()

A = threading.Thread(target=test1)
B = threading.Thread(target=test2)

A.start()
B.start()

A.join()
B.join()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A:0
B:1
A:2
B:3
A:4
B:5
```

Comment: Your code works properly. Because of your explanation, I could know the issue of Python language  itself. Thank you.